# my daughter just clicked a link she got on twitter and want to know is it safe and what does it do

Tags: virus

My daughter received a masked link and clicked it, she knows better but it was masked as google.com/herusername.

```
https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/SetSID?ilo=1&ddb159557ad30bff1245309e7fa3945d=30c932f295d35f2397f95d54f32c2695&ils=a27555d5867549c10d9496979e5a7e38&ilc=0&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fhangouts.google.com%2Flinkredirect%3Fdest%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.baidu.com%252Flink%253Furl%253DZOyN65KmXpWhscXBcmYgQwhJpNccswVJCR2MabIgwM70i15yjHO7b0BGZfaDgesb%2526wd%253D452729b28a73239092af438a28144e42%2526eqid%253Dce723c0037767e80b3852a78ecce168c
```

she has 2 step account verification on google but worried as i do internet banking on the same machine

what is this link and what harm can it do?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't interpret every random link out there, else we will be flooded with links to review.

Comment: On a whim, I did an analysis of the link. It leads to banking malware, it tries to infect your browser, and it tries to install ransomware. Get a professional to take a look and don't do any banking on the machine until you can be assured the machine is safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

— removed due to site policies regarding these kind of questions (there off-topic)

Comment: thank you, we have just changed our google password and revoked access to all other devices. i will now keep an eye on the bank accounts. thanks so much for replying

Comment: @lvB We do not give advice like this without a forensic investigation first. You have no idea what that link does. That's why these types of questions are off-topic. It takes time to figure out what's actually going on.

Comment: Ok, so I did not clearly enough communicated that it’s just based on the url only. I’ll remove my awnser to not have future readers use it. Thnx for the info @schroeder

Comment: Here's the analysis I did: https://cuckoo.ee/analysis/1492868/summary/

Comment: Thnx for the work and link @schroeder